# How do I override extended theme's styles and remove plugins?

Tags: vuepress

I've made my custom theme and extended the basic theme using configuration (index.js):

`extend: '@vuepress/theme-default'`

What I can't accomplish is disabling the plugins and overriding the default styles using (config.js):

```
module.exports = {
    // Disabling plugins we received from parent theme
    plugins: {
        '@vuepress/active-header-links': false,
        '@vuepress/search': false,
        '@vuepress/plugin-nprogress': false,
    },
    ...
```

and (index.styl):

```
// For example
body
    background-color: red !important;
```

When I run the dev server using the `npm run dev` or even after I build the website with `npm run build`, the result is the same. The old theme's plugins and styles stay.

I can even see them when I inspect the fetched CSS files.

I've read the docs but can't understand if this is an issue, or if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. For you to inherit a theme you must to create the file `docs/.vuepress/index.js` :

```js
// docs/.vuepress/index.js
module.exports = {
  extend: '@vuepress/theme-default',
};
```

2. If you want to disable plugins, you must to declare the `plugin-name` with `false`:

```js
// docs/.vuepress/index.js
module.exports = {
  extend: '@vuepress/theme-default',
  plugins: [
    ['@vuepress/active-header-links', false],
    ['@vuepress/search', false],
    ['@vuepress/plugin-nprogress', false],
    ['smooth-scroll', false]    
  ],
};
```

For more information about this [click here](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/inheritance.html#override-plugins)

3. If you want to replace styles, you must to create the file `docs/.vuepress/styles/index.styl`:

```css
/* docs/.vuepress/styles/index.styl */
body {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

This also applies to others styles files present in default-theme. But you should pay attention to that:

> Both the user’s styles/index.styl and the theme’s styles/index.styl are generated into the final CSS file, but the user’s style is generated later and therefore has higher priority.

[Click here](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/miscellaneous/design-concepts.html#overriding) for more information.

4. If you have a lot of changes to the default theme, it is worth creating a new theme, because the inheritance is intended for minor corrections.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)